# How to get Subcaption outside float working for landscape tables?

Tags: tables, floats, captions, subcaption

I use the nice MWE displayed below to display a landscape table (found here: [Tex: How to place table on new page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19017).)

I have one big table (that's why landscape) which I want to split across multiple pages. So I want to split them in multiple tables with subcaption (I did not get longtable working as desired).

This MWE outputs:

*Table 1: This should be table 1A*

*Table 2: This should be table 1B*

(subcaption in alfabet, roman etc)

So my question is **how to get subcaptions working outside floats**.

I found this solution: [Tex: Change caption in table from Table 2 to Table 1A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82226/74646) => however if I combine both snippets it start to complain that subcaptions cannot be used outside floats.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{afterpage}
    \usepackage{capt-of}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum 
    \afterpage{%
        \clearpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{landscape}
            \centering 
            \begin{tabular}{llll}
                A & B & C & D \\
            \end{tabular}
            \captionof{table}{This should be table 1A}
        \end{landscape}
        \clearpage
    }
    \afterpage{
        \clearpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{landscape}
            \centering 
            \begin{tabular}{llll}
                E & F & G & H \\
            \end{tabular}
            \captionof{table}{This should be table 1B}
        \end{landscape}
        \clearpage
    }
    \lipsum 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post your try to combine the snippets, so we can make modifications of it? The "out-of-float" message could be avoided by using `\setcaptiontype{table}` right after `\begin{landscape}` (and using regular `\caption` instead of `\captionof{table}`).